# Autofill a cell in a list if another cell in the same list contains a certain text value

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, auto-populate

I want a cell in a SP list to automatically populate/fill-in if a certain text value is present in a column in the same list.  For example the list contains two columns named: Route of Flight and Spare Parts.

The Route of Flight column is filled in by the planner with a string of text, e.g. KOKC-KLIT-KDFW-KOKC. If the Route of Flight column contains KDFW then I want the Spare Parts column to auto-populate with "NEEDED".  If the route of flight does not contain KDFW then the Spare Parts column should auto-populate with "NOT NEEDED".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a Calculated Column.

1. Add a Calculated Column.
2. Enter a formula like below.

   =IF( ISERROR(SEARCH("KDFW",[Route of Flight])), "NOT NEEDED", "NEEDED" )

Note: SEARCH returns a number if the text is found, or an error if not.

Answer (score 0):

Except using a Calculated column, you can also use InfoPath Designer to customize your list form then use Rules to set field's value.
[Set a field’s value](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-5322d726-b787-4e5f-8d37-ba6db68b451d#__toc269451425)